# Formato incorrecto de mensaje iso 8583 en el lado del servidor J8583

Tags: java

Actualmente estoy trabajando con un proyecto que utiliza j8583 para la creación de este tipo de mensajes.

Para iniciar/mantener la conexión con el servidor se esta realizando el envío de un mensaje echo (0800).

Hasta aquí ningún problema, el mensaje se genera como lo solicita la documentación, el problema viene cuando del lado del servidor me indican que se recibe de manera incorrecta. Veo que el mensaje que les llega esta totalmente en hexadecimal, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, si logran convertir el mensaje a como se envía originalmente, sin embargo indican que no es correcto, la forma de enviar el mensaje debe ser de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podemos observar el mensaje se recibe en claro y no codificado en hexadecimal.
¿Esto tiene alguna configuración en el socket, en el mensaje iso? ¿La fabrica de mensajes?

Mi fabrica la creo a partir de un archivo xml:

```
this.messageFactory = ConfigParser.createFromClasspathConfig("j8583-config.xml");
```

Mi mensaje iso tiene en falso las siguientes banderas:

```
req.setBinaryFields(false);
req.setBinaryHeader(false);
req.setBinary(false);
```

Configuración XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE j8583-config PUBLIC "-//J8583//DTD CONFIG 1.0//EN" "http://j8583.sourceforge.net/j8583.dtd">
<j8583-config>

        <!-- These are the ISO headers to be prepended to the message types specified -->
        <header type="0800">6000050000</header>
        <header type="0810">6000050000</header>

        <template type="0800">
                <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
                <field num="7" type="DATE10" />
                <field num="11" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
                <field num="24" type="NUMERIC" length="3" />
                <field num="41" type="ALPHA" length="8" />
                <field num="42" type="ALPHA" length="15" />
                <field num="60" type="LLLLVAR" length="" />
        </template>


        <parse type="0800">
                <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
                <field num="7" type="DATE10" />
                <field num="11" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
                <field num="24" type="NUMERIC" length="3" />
                <field num="41" type="ALPHA" length="8" />
                <field num="42" type="ALPHA" length="15" />
                <field num="60" type="LLLLVAR" length="" />
        </parse>


</j8583-config>
```

Mensaje ISO:

```
        final IsoMessage req = this.messageFactory.newMessage(NET_INFO_REQUEST.getValue());

        req.setValue(PROCESSING_CODE, ECHO.getValue(), IsoType.NUMERIC, 6);
        req.setValue(TRANSMISSION_DATE_TIME, FormatUtils.formatDate10GMT0(new Date()), IsoType.DATE10, 0);    
        req.setValue(SYSTEM_TRACE_AUDIT_NO, leftPad(simpleTraceGenerator.nextTrace(), 6), IsoType.NUMERIC, 6);    
        req.setValue(INTERNATIONAL_NETWORK_ID, command.VISA.getCode(), IsoType.NUMERIC, 4);
        req.setValue(TERMINAL_ID, "72024092", IsoType.ALPHA, 8);    
        req.setValue(CLIENT_CODE, "03659307       ", IsoType.ALPHA, 15);    
        req.setValue(SOFTWARE_VERSION, "OPv1", IsoType.LLLLVAR, 0);
        req.setBinary(false);
```

Gracias desde ya.

Comment: Podríás incluir los detalles relevantes del código con el que _envías_ el mensaje? Los detalles de configuración en el XML?

Comment: @Alfabravo, agrego los detalles del mensaje, gracias

Answer (score 0):

lo que se puede ver al revisar la implementación es:

- En el [IsoMessage](https://sourceforge.net/p/j8583/code/HEAD/tree/j8583/src/main/java/com/solab/iso8583/IsoMessage.java) no necesitas el `req.setBinary` (que además no funciona porque `fale` no es un valor booleano válido) porque por defecto eso va en `false`.
- En el [MessageFactory](https://sourceforge.net/p/j8583/code/HEAD/tree/j8583/src/main/java/com/solab/iso8583/MessageFactory.java) también va por defecto el `useBinaryMessages` en false.

Lo único que se podría ver ahí es que `this.messageFactory.newMessage(NET_INFO_REQUEST.getValue());` esté recibiendo un valor diferente a `0800` o `0810` y que lo esté procesando de otra forma...

Comment: Gracias por responder:

Te comento, tuve un error al editar en contenido en cuanto a req.setBinary.

para lo del newMessage, el varlor que se envia es el 0x800 ->     NET_INFO_REQUEST(0x800),